# finger search on a red black tree

Tags: terminology, data-structures, search-trees

I'm having trouble finding materials on what 'finger search' is, in the context of a red black tree.

Even Wikipedia has a very short page about that, could you refer me or explain what kind of search is that.

Comment: Trying using a search engine.

Comment: You could help by adding what you know about finger search in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the basic operations supported by trees is searching for elements. A balanced binary tree (for example, a red-black tree) supports search in $O(\log n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of elements. In some scenarios, the elements we are searching for are close to one another, and *finger search* allows taking advantage of that. After having just searched the $j$th largest element, searching the $i$th largest elements only takes time $O(\log |i-j|)$. So scanning through all the elements in order would only take $O(n)$ time rather than $O(n\log n)$.

Finger search can be implemented using several different data structures. In particular, it can be implemented using balanced binary trees such as red-black trees.

For more on finger search, check out a [research proposal](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~maverick/Research/proposal.pdf) by Maverick Woo and a [book chapter](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/finger05.pdf) by Gerth Stølting Brodal.

Comment: I think you're talking about selection, the 'finger search' I'm trying to understand involves traveling along the right/left most path of the tree and finding the node in O(log d) time. d supposed to be the distance...

Comment: That's the same thing: $d = |i-j|$ is the distance between the current item and the previous one.